# Referential integrity constraint violation on save

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, liquibase

I need your help, cause i can't understand what's wrong and it's annoying me
I create two tables with one-to-one relationship by liquibase:

```
    <changeSet id="create user_profile_info table" author="aarexer">
    <createTable tableName="user_profile_info">
        <column name="id" type="BIGINT" autoIncrement="true">
            <constraints primaryKey="true" nullable="false"/>
        </column>
        <column name="user_id" type="BIGINT"/>
    </createTable>
</changeSet>


<changeSet id="create users table" author="aarexer">
    <createTable tableName="users">
        <column name="id" type="BIGINT" autoIncrement="true">
            <constraints primaryKey="true" nullable="false"/>
        </column>
    </createTable>

    <addForeignKeyConstraint baseColumnNames="id"
                             baseTableName="users"
                             constraintName="fk_user_to_user_profile"
                             referencedColumnNames="user_id"
                             referencedTableName="user_profile_info"/>
</changeSet>
```

And write java entities for it with this relationship, this is the `UserProfileInfo`:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_profile_info")
public class UserProfileInfo implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GenericGenerator(name = "native", strategy = "native")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "native")
    private Long id;

    public UserProfileInfo() {
    }

    public UserProfileInfo(String phoneNumber) {
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }
}
```

And this is the `User` entity:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GenericGenerator(name = "native", strategy = "native")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "native")
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName = "user_id")
    private UserProfileInfo userProfileInfo;

    // Hibernate requires a no-arg constructor
    public User() {

    }

    public User(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
}
```

It's one directional link, from User to UserProfile.

It's all good at first glance, but when i try to save it:

```
UserProfileInfo entity = new UserProfileInfo("98518872");
        User user = new User("Aleksandr");
        user.setUserProfileInfo(entity);

        userRepository.save(user);
```

I see `Referential integrity constraint violation` error cause `fk_user_to_user_profile`.

What's wrong?

I create user and user_info objects, link it by setters and have graph of the objects. And i can't save my graph.

I think may be error in the addForeignKeyConstraint, cause when i delete this constraint it works(and this is understandable), but how i should save objects with constraints on tables?

Please, help me to understand my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and it is really hard to understand the reason.
What fixed my issue was adding nullable false in `@JoinColumn`

```
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName = "user_id", nullable = false)
private UserProfileInfo userProfileInfo;
```

Comment: Thanx for you answer!
But it doesn't work for me, i tried

Comment: Do you understand the reason?

Answer (score 0):

I change my liquibase migrations and set constraint on column:

```
    <column name="user_id" type="BIGINT">
        <constraints references="users(id)" foreignKeyName="fk_user_to_user_profile"/>
    </column>
```

After this it all works fine and save my graph of objects